# Modx Evo / Debian 9: Cannot open file (/assets/cache//sitePublishing.idx.php)

Tags: debian, modx, modx-evolution

Just re installed an old modx website on another server. But I can access only to the home page. When i try to publish a resource i got the error message :

> Cannot open file (/assets/cache//sitePublishing.idx.php)

I understand that the "//" should be "/" but is there a  config file or something somewhere where i can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The file **sitePublishing.idx.php** handles the caching of Modx pages.

You need to give proper permissions to the assets/cache directory and clear the cache from the Modx manager.

If the problem persists you could try manually removing the sitePublishing.idx.php file (it might needs write permission) and Modx will automatically regenerate it.